# Usando PHP, como é que consigo ir buscar valores as tabelas?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Sou novo nisto da programacao, mas queria saber como é que faço para ir buscar informação às tabelas,usando as PK da do meio, aqui tão as tabelas:

[image: Tabelas]

O código que tenho atualmente da query é este:

```
$resultado = $ligacao->query("SELECT cursos_has_lisboa.*
FROM ((cursos_has_lisboa
INNER JOIN cursos ON cursos_has_lisboa.cursos_ID_curso = cursos.ID_curso)
INNER JOIN lisboa ON cursos_has_lisboa.lisboa_ID_escola = lisboa.ID_escola)
ORDER BY cursos_has_lisboa.lisboa_ID_escola");
```

Comment: Pra que esses parênteses?

Comment: Segui-me por isto: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp